How to Minimize Effort in Maintaining Custom Modifications to Tomcat Source Code Across Releases?
I have custom modifications to Tomcat’s source code, but applying these changes becomes a repetitive effort whenever a new Tomcat release is issued. What are the best practices or strategies to minimize the effort required to maintain these changes across updates?
I attempted using custom patches and applying them to the source code, but as the source code evolves, line changes make this approach impractical.

Enable git rerere
